# Can't make an image element full screen in a full screen modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal which takes the full width and height of a browser.In the modal there is an image within a div and some other elements,now I am trying to make the image full screen in the browser as like as a youtube video acts full screen, I have added a button and implemented full screen API in it for the purpose but it does not work.

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus();
});

$('#dicomModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').focus();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});

$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker8').datetimepicker({

  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({

  });
});


var myImage = document.getElementById('myImage');
var dicomFull = document.getElementById('dicomFull');

if (dicomFull) {
  dicomFull.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (myImage.requestFullscreen) {
      myImage.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (myImage.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      myImage.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (myImage.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      myImage.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (myImage.msRequestFullscreen) {
      myImage.msRequestFullscreen();
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.dicomv {
  &__mods {
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
  &__items {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1rem;
  }
  &__navbar {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    min-height: 60px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 80;
  }
  &__next {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
    background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "bg-col");
    &: hover {
      color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
      background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "bg-col");
    }
    &:focus {
      color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
      background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "bg-col");
    }
  }
  &__fs {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
    background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "button", "btn-col");
    &: hover {
      color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
      background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "button", "btn-col");
    }
    &:focus {
      color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
      background-color: map-deep-get($colors, "button", "btn-col");
    }
  }
  &__container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
  }
  &__button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -3.5rem;
    color: map-deep-get($colors, "background", "base");
  }
  &__wid {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
  }
  &__mod {
    &--d {
      top: 0 !important;
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
#viewArea {
  margin-left: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: map-deep-get($colors, "font", "para")
}
.viewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute
}
.imageViewer {
  height: 100%;
}
.viewportWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}
.viewer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.dicom-sidebar-container {
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.dicom-main-container-with-sidebar {
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
}
.dicom-main-container-without-sidebar {
  width: 100%;
}
//
.dicom-sidebar {
  /*margin: 0;*/
}
.panel-heading {
  padding: 2px 8px;
}
.panel-container {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.dicom-sidebar-panel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.dicom-sidebar-panel-body {
  padding: 0 10px 100px 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.dicom-sidebar-row {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.dicom-sidebar-drawer {
  margin-left: -240px;
}
.dicom-sidebar-inner-box {
  width: 110px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  z-index: 100;
  float: left;
}
.dicom-sidebar-inner-box:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 6px;
}
:-webkit-full-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
:-moz-full-screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="dialog" class="modal dicomv__mods" id="dicomModal" style="z-index: 1050; display:">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg dicomv__wid">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
    <div id="" class="dicomv">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default dicomv__navbar">
        <div class="dicom-navbar-container">

          <ul class="">

            <li class="dicomv__items">
              <a href="#">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dicomv__fs" id="dicomFull" name="button">View FullScreen</button>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="viewArea" class="row">
        <div id="dicom_loadbar"></div>
        <div class="dicom-sidebar-container panel panel-default dicom-sidebar-panel">
          <div class="panel-heading">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body dicom-sidebar-panel-body">

          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dicomv__container dicom-main-container dicom-main-container-with-sidebar" id="myImage">

          <div id="myImage">
            <img src="http://images.newseveryday.com/data/thumbs/full/27419/570/0/0/0/macbook-pro.jpg" id="" alt="" />

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first thing to do would be to drastically simplify your question. Pare everything down to be the most basic parts. This will a) make it easier for others to see what the important parts are, and b) make it easier to see what the problem is (there would be no extraneous code that has no bearing in the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a 100% width on your image for it to scale to fill the container when you go full screen. So this probably won't be your final code, but as an example:

```
if(dicomFull){
dicomFull.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(myImage.requestFullscreen){
    myImage.requestFullscreen();
  }else if (myImage.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    myImage.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }else if (myImage.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    myImage.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }else if (myImage.msRequestFullscreen) {
    myImage.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
  $("#myImage img").css("width", "100%");

});
}
```

Comment: not working, I want to make the image to take full viewport screen just like it happens to youtube video. I have heard that this is not possible with JS or jQuery in this project as I am using Angular in the view layer of this project,so it should be done using Angular,is it really the solution?if so can anyone help?